# how are String objects immutable in this case?

Tags: java

I agree with the fact that the String objects are immutable, means they cannot be modified. Like in the case below

```
String str = "Hi";
String str1 = str.concat("Nilesh");
```

Here the str object will be returned if the length argument is 0 or a new String object will be created and its reference will be returned.
And if i do

```
String str = "Hi";
str="Hello";
```

How is it getting changed? where does immutable comes into picture? An example please.

Comment: A common misconception is that `String str` means `str` is a `String` object.  Instead it means that `str` is a **reference** to a `String` object.  So you can change the reference without changing the object referenced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is immutable is the String itself, not the reference that points to the String. In your second code:

```
String str = "hi";
str = "hello";
```

There are 2 String objects involved: `"hi"` and `"hello"`.

`str` is a reference that originally points to the first one then points to the second one following an assignment. But the String object `"hi"` does not get modified in that code.

Comment: So how is StringBuffer coming in picture?

Comment: @BundleContext.. What do you mean? StringBuffer (which by the way is obsolete apart from very specific use cases) is a totally different class.

Comment: I read in complete reference "StringBuffer is a peer class of String that provides much of the functionality of strings.As you know, String represents fixed-length, immutable character sequences. In contrast,StringBuffer represents growable and writeable character sequences." As String.concat() creates a new String object. What happens in stringbuffer.append()

Comment: stringbuffer.append modifies the stringbuffer, it does not create a new object. Note: stringbuilder should be used instead of stringbuffer.

Comment: @BundleContext.. That is indeed the only case where you could prefer a StringBuffer. But they generally are local variables so thread safety is not an issue and you would use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing immutability with changing the reference.

This code:

```
String str = "Hi"; // str now refers to the String "Hi"
str = "Hello";  // str now refers to the String "Hello"
```

just changes the `String` object to which `str` refers; `str` is a *variable* that holds a reference to a `String` object. Nothing happened to mutate either the `"Hi"` or the `"Hello"` object.

If String were mutable, it would have a method like `setValue(String s)` that could be called to alter its state, so you might be able to do this:

```
String str = "Hi";
str.setValue("Hello"); // if String were mutable
```

Answer (score 1):

`"Hello"` is completely different object of `String` so you can no longer refer to `"Hi"`

> Immutability is not about Reference it is about object state. If state is changed new object is created.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html

> An object is considered immutable if its state cannot change after it is constructed.

Answer (score 1):

`str` is a **variable**.  The term "variable" means that the variable may be assigned various strings, one at a time.  Each string is still immutable.

Answer (score 1):

If the others said `"Hello"` is another `String`. I think you can see the fact that is a new `String` best when using [`System.identityHashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29). Just try it out:

```
String str = "Hi";
System.out.println("try 1: "+System.identityHashCode(str));
str="Hello";
System.out.println("try 2: "+System.identityHashCode(str));
```

`System.identityHashCode` will usually return the reference  itself (but you cannot rely on that fact).

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "Hi";

str="Hello";
```

*String* is immutable so we cant modify the String Object.

Here, Two object will be created, We can verify through hashcode.

String str = "Hi";

System.out.println("Str(Hi)-hashcode: "+str.hashCode());

```
str="Hello";

System.out.println("Str(Hello)-hashcode: "+str.hashCode());
```

In Both cases *HashCode* value will be different.

> 1st case-> Str(Hi)-hashcode: 2337
>
> 2nd case-> Str(Hello)-hashcode: 69609650

Answer (score 0):

case 1:

```
String str = "Hi";
String str1 = str.concat("Nilesh");
```

total of 3 string objects are created

case 2:

```
String str = "Hi";
str="Hello";
```

in this case 2 string objects are created.
when line 1 is executed str referes to "Hi".
when line 2 is executed str refers to "Hello" and isolates "Hi".
str just refers to "Hello" after line2